How do I apply user selections to QuickReport preview, correctly and efficiently?
I have an old project using QuickReport in Delphi 10 Seattle. I based the entire solution on the ClosePreview() call.
I tried changing the QRPrinter object, Printer object, or TQuickRep(QRUserPreview.QRPrinter.Master), but chaotically and without full success.
How do I read the user's selections from PrinterSetupDialog correctly? How do I apply the user's selections to the report preview?
For example, the user selects Printer '<Name> ...', Orientation, and Format (e.g. 'Envelope DL', 'Envelope CL').
How do I setup PrinterSetupDialog with the user's selections?

Do you use a TReportDesignDialog somewhere? It has a TQRDPrinterSettings sub-component...
